# selectBooleanCheckbox ajax event fires but the listener is never executed

Tags: ajax, listener

The selectBooleanCheckbox ajax event fires but the listener is never executed.
If I remove the c:forEach and just call the first one in the list it works.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Controller.graphFilter.get(0).checked}" >
       <p:ajax listener="#{Controller.addMessage}" />  
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

notes:
graphFilter is a list where container has the sets/gets for checked and description.
controller is a viewscoped managed bean.
addMessage public function that puts a message for the growl.
Everything is in the same form.

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="false">
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>

<c:forEach items="#{Controller.graphFilter}" var="Gc">
     <h:outputText value="#{Gc.description}" />  
         <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Gc.checked}"  >
            <p:ajax listener="#{Controller.addMessage}"/>
         </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>                                       
</c:forEach>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your components with a p:column:

```
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{Gc.description}" />  
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Gc.checked}"  >
            <p:ajax listener="#{Controller.addMessage}"/>
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:column>
```

But replacing the whole structure with a [p:dataList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dataListHome.jsf) would be more elegant.